# Ajax can not give success response

Tags: php, ajax

I am fetching subject details of student based on name and admission_year which is getting from ajax call but ajax can not give success response so subject field can not display subject. Plz need solution how to get success message. Is there any wrong in my coding?
The whole coding is shown below.
script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#branch_name,#class_name').on('change', function(){
    //gender_new = $('#gender_new option:selected').val();

    class_name = $('#class_name option:selected').val();
    branch_name = $('#branch_name option:selected').val();
    name=$('#name').val();
    admission_year=$('#admission_year').val();

    $.ajax({
        type :'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data : { class_name : class_name, branch_name : branch_name, name : name, admission_year : admission_year },
        url : 'tc_search.php',
        success : function(result){
         $('#subject1').val(result['subject1']);
         $('#subject2').val(result['subject2']);

        }
    });

});
</script>
```

tc_search.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

$class_name=$_POST['class_name'];
$admission_year=$_POST['admission_year'];
$name=$_POST['name']
$branch_name=$_POST['branch_name'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM admit_senior WHERE name = '$name' and admission_year='$admission_year'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo json_encode($row);

?>
```

html:

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="admission_year" name="admission_year" readonly <?php echo "value='{$row1['admission_year']}' "?>/>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" <?php echo "value='{$row1['name']}' "?>/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">2) He/She appeared/did not appear examination:</label>
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Branch Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <select id="branch_name" name ="branch_name" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled readonly>Select branch</option>
    <option value="B.A">B.A</option>
    <option value="B.Com">B.Com</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Class Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <select id="class_name" name ="class_name" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled readonly>Select Class</option>
    <option value="Part-I">Part-I</option>
    <option value="Part-II">Part-II</option>
    <option value="Part-III">Part-III</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">1.</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject1" id="subject1"/>
    </div>

    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">2.</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject2" id="subject2"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Have you check the network inspector you browser?
Does the request return any error?
If you are using php 7 you need to wrap $name and $admission_year with {}.

Comment: @leli.1337 basic parsing of variables inside double-quoted strings still works the same in PHP 7, there should be no need to wrap them in { … }

Comment: do with `$('#subject1').val(result.subject1);`

Comment: use console.log to check success and error as well

Comment: i hope my answer will help u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** of all `mysql_*` is deprecated long time ago and closed in PHP 7.

Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statement, which will help you to prevent your code with SQL Injection.

**Second**, use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to check either getting result or not then you can use `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Issue in your code is that, you are using `json_encode()` for your result. but fetching result like `result['subject2']` which is wrong, you can get the result from json response as like

```
result.subject2
```

its better to use `console.log(result)` and check result in browser console for debugging.

Some useful links:

[Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: console.log(result) is not give output send me detail coding

Comment: @Nikhilkorade: what not working..  use this `print_r($row); exit;` before this line `echo json_encode($row);` and share the result

Comment: result will be shown in browser console , Ajax's response section @Nikhilkorade

Comment: that result is not display in control i think control is not going to tc_search.php

Comment: @Nikhilkorade: check browser console or network tab, where you can see your ajax request

Comment: @Nikhilkorade use `alert('here');` after this line in jquery `$('#branch_name,#class_name').on('change', function(){` are u getting alert or not

Comment: yes, i get alert with all value that i had send through ajax.

Comment: @Nikhilkorade: if ajax not working then u definitely getting some errors in console.

Comment: use these `<option selected value="">Select Class</option>
<option selected value="">Select branch</option>` first option of your dropdowns @Nikhilkorade

Comment: @Nikhilkorade: i hope u got the solution

Comment: then resolve jquery error first. which you are getting in console @Nikhilkorade

Comment: glad to help u @Nikhilkorade

Comment: hello need help in ajax success. I want to return multiple result into single result with comm separated of following variable   var subject=result.subject2+result.subject3+result.subject4;

Comment: @nikhilkorade no not like that . use each in jquery inside ajax response this will use for loop and I think u also need to use json stringify ... Need to use loop in jquwry